# Why strange printing from threads with mutex

Tags: c++, multithreading

I thought that this code, in which I used mutex to synchronize between threads, would print elegantly numbers from 0 to 10, 3 times in row.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

struct A
{   
    void run() 
    {       
        lock_guard<mutex> l(mutex);
        int i = 0;
        while (i <= 10)
            cout << "i = " << i++ << endl;            
    }

    std::mutex mut;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    thread t1(&A::run, &a);
    thread t2(&A::run, &a);
    thread t3(&A::run, &a);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
}
```

But for some reason the beginning of the output is always more or less corrupted. The rest is sometimes ok, sometimes not. So, clearly, it is not synchronized. It is strange, because I expected that when one thread gets a lock on the mutex, no other thread will enter the body of the run method. But clearly it is not true.

```
i = i = 00i = 0

i = 1
i = 2
i = 3
```

Could someone explain this?

I thought that maybe I need to surround the 'a' object in the thread constructor with std::ref, but no, this doesn't help.

Comment: Some people, when confronted with a problem, think, "I know, I'll use threads," and then two they hav erpoblesms.

Comment: `lock_guard<mutex> l(mutex);` and `std::mutex mut;`?

Comment: Not helpful, but I find the use of the lock not compelling.  Make a print method that has the lock guard, and call the print method from within the loop.  Locks should be as minimally blocking as possible. No point in blocking all 'run' methods when you only need to guard the printing.

Comment: It's probably a typo. Should be `lock_guard<mutex> l(mut);` Your compiler is likely to issue a warning. That's why `using namespace std;` is bad practice.

Comment: Aaaah, typo, OMG :-) It should have been 'mut', not 'mutex'. Thanks, it works now.

Comment: It is from the same code. See yourself: https://wandbox.org/permlink/GGgnClDMi7Y9yILi

Comment: Lesson learnt. Great. :-)

Comment: @Slava underrated comment xD

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This:

```
lock_guard<mutex> l(mutex);
```

declares a function `l` of type `lock_guard<mutex>` accepting a `std::mutex` parameter which is probably not what you wanted. A race condition occurs since there is no proper use of [std::lock_guard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) wrapper. You want to declare a variable of type `std::lock_guard` and initialize it with a `mut` member variable instead:

```
std::lock_guard<std::mutex> l(mut);
```

To avoid this confusion don't use `using namespace std;`.

Comment: In interesting twist on the Most Vexing Parse.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that I made a typo. Instead of writing 'mut' I typed 'mutex'. The code surprisingly compiled, but, as noted in the comments, this way I declared a function, not locked a mutex ('most vexing parse'). That is why the code of 'run' method was not synchronized between threads.

As noted in the comments, also not using 'using namespace std' would prevent me from this error, as I would have quickly noticed that I didn't have a member variable 'std::mutex', but 'mut'.

Answer (score 0):

It was the typo referenced: 'Should be lock_guard l(mut);' but still, try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

struct A
{   
    void run() 
    {       
        int i = 0;
        while (i <= 10)
            printOutput(i);
    }

    void printOutput(int i)
    {
        lock_guard<mutex> l(mut);
        cout << "i = " << i++ << endl;            
    }

    std::mutex mut;
};

int main()
{
    A a;
    thread t1(&A::run, &a);
    thread t2(&A::run, &a);
    thread t3(&A::run, &a);

    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
}
```

I think you'll find the output more interesting... sometimes.  Try it with debug compile on and optimized - they may behave differently.